# How to rotate over HTML elements when pressing Tab key?

Tags: javascript, html

***Without using JQuery***
How to rotate over HTML elements when pressing Tab key??
For example
In this form

```
<form>
    Field 1: <input type="text" id="field1" tabindex=1 /><br />
    Field 2: <input type="text" id="field2" tabindex=2 /><br />
    Field 3: <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex=3 /><br />
    Field 4: <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex=4 /><br />     
</form>
```

When user press Tab key continuously
The focused items will be
field1 -> field2 -> field3 -> field4 -> field1 -> field2 -> field3 -> field4 -> field1 -> ...
And so on

Comment: What do you really want to ask?

Comment: Having the tab rotate back to the first field is bad for accessibility, if someone must use keyboard for navigation (e.g., blind users) they will not be able to access other parts of the page.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp want to rotate ONLY over this form HTML items not rotate over all items in the page

Comment: @JaredMcAteer thanks .. good design note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this *AFTER* field4:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myInput = document.getElementById("field4");
if(myInput.addEventListener ) {
    myInput.addEventListener('keydown',this.keyHandler,false);
} else if(myInput.attachEvent ) {
    myInput.attachEvent('onkeydown',this.keyHandler); /* damn IE hack */
}

function keyHandler(e) {
    var TABKEY = 9;
    if(e.keyCode == TABKEY) {
        if(e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        document.getElementById('field1').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to thank the community. This is my first contribution after years of obtaining answers from you guys.

Yesterday I was looking for some examples of how to do this. Finally I did my own **code based on arrows navigation** because, as JaredMcAteer pointed out, tabbing shouldn't rotate inside a list for accessibility reasons, but jumping along the total index of active elements. Here you can find the code. Hope it helps somebody.

```js
$('[role="menu"] li:first-child a').focus();
$('[role="menu"] a').keydown(function(e){
  var myIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  var mySibling = $(this).parents('[role="menu"]').children();
  var first = mySibling[0];
  var last = mySibling.get(-1);
  if (e.which === 38 || e.keyCode === 38){
   e.preventDefault();
   var prev = mySibling[myIndex - 1];
   if(prev){
    $(prev).children('a').focus();
   }else {
    $(last).children('a').focus();
   }
  }
  if (e.which === 40 || e.keyCode === 40){
   e.preventDefault();
   var next = mySibling[myIndex + 1];
   if(next){
    $(next).children('a').focus();
   }else {
    $(first).children('a').focus();
   }
  }
 });
```

```css
.menu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.313rem;
 background: #ccc;
 opacity: 1;
}
.menu li {
  display: block;
}
.menu li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0.313rem;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li:nth-last-child(n+2) {
 border-bottom: solid 1px #fff; 
}
.menu ul a:hover, .menu ul a:focus {
 background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu" role="menubar">
   <li role="menuitem"><a href="#target22" title="" class="settingsIcon">nav Item</a>
    <ul id="target22"  role="menu">
     <li role="menuitem" class="active"><a href="#menu1" title="">First Menu Item of the menu collection</a></li>
     <li role="menuitem"><a href="#menu2" title="">Menu Item</a></li>
     <li role="menuitem"><a href="#menu3" title="">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tab should rotate through form elements in all modern browsers. You can force the cursor to autofocus on the 1st item in the list by using the html5 `autofocus` attribute. Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/LDfGd)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    Field 1: <input type="text" id="field1" tabindex=1  autofocus="autofocus" /><br />
    Field 2: <input type="text" id="field2" tabindex=2 /><br />
    Field 3: <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex=3 /><br />
    Field 4: <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex=4 /><br />     
</form>
```

@JaredMcAteer is absolutely right in that using autofocus can degrade the experience for users, especially those with accessibility concerns. Please take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this. Give the last div or whatever on your form a tabindex and then when it gets focus just move the focus to the first element on your form. I haven't set explicit tabindex on my fields so using tabindex=0 works.

```
var $last = $(".ok-cancel");
$last.attr("tabindex", "0");
$last.on("focus", function(){ ... move focus to first field ... }));
```

This has the advantage that you do not need to know what else is on the form other than the first input (which you can discover automatically if needed).

PS: I know the question says no jQuery but thats what my code is in.